# google play game realtime multiplayer how to get quickmatch player's name?

Tags: google-play, google-play-services, multiplayer, google-play-games

i am trying to use google API to make my realtime multiplayer game. I noticed that everytime the players play with each other using the "random match" option, their IDs are different from their actual google IDs...
Is there a way to retrieve their actual google IDs on random match and to not use these strange IDs?

Comment: I think you are referring to **playerIds** and **participantIds**. ParticipantIds change from match to match whereas the  the PlayerId is permanent for every player. Which one are you trying to retrieve?

Comment: playerID. More specifically, the name of the user who logged using his google account. The random match just bugs this playerID to some random value every time

Comment: Oh so you're just trying to find his name. **Player** class and **Participant** class both have methods called **getDisplayName()** So I dont think it matters which one you get.

Comment: Also, I don't think random match changes playerID, playerID is permanent for every player, if you are getting another id, it probably means it's another player. If you post code i'll be more than happy to help you out.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I have found you can't for auto-match.

From - https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/realtimeMultiplayer#quick_game_option

> However, to preserve anonymity, players who joined the room via auto-match will only have a participant ID (and not a player ID).

However if you sent the persons name to the other device as a message - That could be an option

Comment: Would that be a violation of the Google Terms of Services? The idea is great but I'm afraid of google :)

Comment: I imagine if you asked the player first it wouldn't be a problem